# pypfop 0.2.0 and environment variable FOP_CMD

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf-generation, apache-fop, pypfop

I'm trying to get working pypfop 0.2.0 with [this tutorial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypfop/0.2.0). Unfortunately I'm not able to pass through step 2.2:

> Decompress in wherever place you like and set environment variable FOP_CMD to the bin/fop of the decompressed folder.

Links seem broken so I downloaded binary package [from here](ftp://mirror.hosting90.cz/apache/xmlgraphics/fop/) but suppose it doesn't matter. However, if I decompress the package no path `bin/fop` is presneted.

My current `FOP_CMD` setup (I've decompressed fop package into `~/utils`):

```
$ echo $FOP_CMD
~/utils/fop-1.1
```

Now I get this exception if I try to run example from the tutorial:

```
Exception: Unable to find the path to execute FOP.Check the environment variable "FOP_CMD"
```

The question is, what should be environment variable `FOP_CMD` set for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've finally found out the answer and it is very simple: the correct way is `fop-1.1/fop`.