# Python doesn't recognize environment variable

Tags: python, environment-variables, xsl-fo

I am trying do convert XSL-FO to PDF following [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypfop) tutorial, but to do that I need to run a command that uses an environment variable called FOP_CMD:

```
doc = Document(tfactory('/home/username/Downloads/file.fo'))
doc.generate(params, oformat='pdf')
```

I saved the environment variable in the file `~/etc/environment` and if I run `echo $FOP_CMD` in the terminal it gives me the right path: `/home/username/fop-1.1`.

However, when running the application, the compiler tells me the following: `Exception: Unable to find the path to execute FOP.Check the environment variable "FOP_CMD"`

The weird thing is that in Windows I am able to run the command without any problems and the envirnment variable points to the same path but in Ubuntu this erros shows up.

I also tried to change the path to `/home/username/fop-1.1/fop` (following the advice given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236826/pypfop-0-2-0-and-environment-variable-fop-cmd) post) but it keeps giving the same error.

Does anyone know what can I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try and get python to print the `FOP_CMD` variable to help narrow down the problem. You need to add `import os` and then `print(os.environ['FOP_CMD']`. See [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ).

Comment: Weird... it gives me this error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(os.environ['FOP_CMD'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'FOP_CMD'`
But if I try to print the PATH path it prints it ok. Do you know what could be the cause of this error?

Comment: Well that `KeyError` indicates that Python doesn't have any record your `FOP_CMD` variable. Can you try specifying the variable explicitly when you run the command like this: `FOP_CMD="/home/username/fop-1.1" yourscript.py`>

Comment: Well, that way it works: `sudo FOP_CMD="/home/username/fop-1.1" python main.py `. But isn't there a way to make this "persistent"? Because this is not the right way to run the program.

Comment: can you please post your `~/etc/environment`?

Comment: @MaxSpencer answer worked, but for the sake of curiosity this is `~/etc/environment content`: `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
FOP_CMD="/home/username/fop-1.1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable inside your Python program like so:

```
import os

if not 'FOP_CMD' in os.environ:
    os.environ['FOP_CMD'] = '/home/username/fop-1.1'
```